# Why 'Mobilisten framework' works well with swift project and not with objective-c projects, when added via pods

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, undeclared-identifier

I have added Mobilisten framework through pods, following instructions on https://www.zoho.com/salesiq/help/developer-section/ios-mobile-sdk-installation.html.

While it builds and runs successfully in a Swift project, I’m getting errors when I try using the framework in an objective-C project workspace.

I’m trying to access *ZohoSalesIQ* and *ZohoSalesIQDelegate*, but I'm not able to.

For example: `[ZohoSalesIQ showLiveChat:TRUE]`;

I'm getting errors like:
“Use of undeclared identifier ‘ZohoSalesIQ’ ”,
“Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ZohoSalesIQDelegate’ ”

I can see that there’s no @objc used for 'ZohoSalesIQ'  in the 'Mobilisten-Swift.h' file. Whether there is any problem with Mobilisten framework or not, is what I’m trying to find out.

Please let me know if anyone is able to successfully install the framework through pods and use ZohoSalesIQ in objective-C project workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the pod repo and running it on device helped achieve the required result. The same did not work out on simulator, it showed 2 compile time errors. But ran successfully on the device.

Comment: This happened to me as well. For some reason I seem to be unable to it to work on the simulator but can build to my device.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed from version `3.1.0` and above!.

You can find the Release Notes for the update [here](https://github.com/zoho/SalesIQ-Mobilisten-iOS/releases/tag/v3.1.0).

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Project Target' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Mobilisten', '3.1.0'
end
```

Add the above version of Mobilisten to your Podfile and run `pod repo update && pod install`